# Получить номер недели Pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

Есть столбец в датафрейме с датой

```
date:     |
__________|
2019-10-12|
__________|
2019-10-20|
__________|
```

Как получить столбцы с годом, месяцем и неделей?

Comment: Номер недели в месяце, в году? Если в месяце, то что это такое, не очевидно

Comment: номер недели в году

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая строка, если колонка не datetime типа

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['week'] = df['date'].dt.week


       date  year  month  week
0 2019-10-12  2019     10    41
1 2019-10-20  2019     10    42
```

или, что тоже самое

```
df.assign(year = df['date'].dt.year, month=df['date'].dt.month, week=df['date'].dt.week)
```